# Where to call setState to update props correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Fairly new to React, and I'm making a quiz app where I need to do the following

1. Create a random array of 40 questions from an external JS file (QuizData object) of 100 questions. This works fine, although because React is not Vanilla JS I am wondering where I should store them, or if I should just declare a function like you can see below.
2. I then need to call setState({questions: questionSet}) to assign these new questions to my state.
3. I need to use this in my question component `<Question data={questions[QNum]} />`, which is currently throwing up an error because `questions[QNum]` is undefined.

```
  loadQuestions = () => {
    let arr = [];
    let questionSet = [];
    while (arr.length < 40) {
      var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      if (arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
    }
    arr.sort((a, b) => a - b).forEach((i) => questionSet.push(QuizData[i - 1]));
    this.setState({
      questions: questionSet,
    });
  };
```

...My issues seem to be coming from React's reconciliation process and that setState is called asyncronously. The render function is called before setState is finished.

Where should I be calling setState to load those questions in? I was looking at doing it in componentWillmount(), but that has been deprectated, and I have tried using a callback in setState, but no luck there. Just looking for the best practice for approaching this type of thing.

Thanks

Comment: Using `functional setState` should solve your problem and that is also the recommended practice.
But you say, that you have already tried and no luck with it.
Can you share a codesandbox of the problem?

Comment: Assuming `<Question/>` is part of the render function of the same component where you have loadQuestions defined, I think you need to specify a key for your `<Question>` component so that it is re rendered after you set the state.

Comment: What is `QNum` here and how are you calling `<Question data={questions[QNum]} />`? Post all of the relevant code.

Comment: Looks like `QuizData` is static. If so, I recommend extracting all the random-generating stuff outside of your component (it has nothing to do with your component) to a regular function and then using the answer below to just set it as state in the constructor of your component `this.state = { question: generateRandomQuestions(); }`

Comment: @palaѕн ```QNum``` is defined in my state, I destructured it later on. It will be an integer between 1 and 40 as the user cycles through the quiz it will be used to define which question they are on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call your `loadQuestions` function in side `componentDidMount`

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.state = {questions : [] , ... };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
         this.loadQuestions();
    }

    ...

}
```

in your render method, before you render `Question` component 
check if it's not undefined

```
render() {

    ...
    return (
        questions[QNum] ? <Question data={questions[QNum]} /> : <h1>Loading Questions...</h1>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have needed (static) data, it would be great to assign the state inside the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   // Set the questionSet

   this.state = { questions: questionSet };
}
```

Comment: +1 to your second snippet, -1 to your first. If the data is already in props, then you don't need it (and shouldn't put it) in state. Common error for new-to-react devs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to store the `questions` in a state. Then map the questions to `Question` components list and render it. Like this:

```
class Quiz extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            questions: [],
        }
        this.loadQuestions = this.loadQuestions.bind(this);
    }

    loadQuestions() {
        let arr = [];
        let questionSet = [];
        while (arr.length < 40) {
          var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
          if (arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
        }
        arr.sort((a, b) => a - b).forEach((i) => questionSet.push(QuizData[i - 1]));
        this.setState({
          questions: questionSet,
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadQuestions();
    }

    render() {
        let questions = [];

        this.state.forEach( question => {
            questions.push( <Question key={question.ID} data={question} /> );
        })

        return (
            <div>{questions}</div>
        )
    }
}
```